# how to select data from another column in the same query?

Tags: mysql, subquery

Sorry about the poorly worded question.. but I don't know how else to explain this...

MySQL... I have a query with several extremely complex subqueries in it. I and selecting from a table and I need to find out what "place" each record is in according to a variety of criteria .. So I have this

```
 Select record.id, record.title 
    (select count(*) from (complex-query-that-returns-newer-records)) as agePlace,           
    (select count(*) from (complex-query-that-returns-records-with-better-ROI)) as ROIPlace...
 From record...
```

Now the issue is that the query is slow - as I had expected give the amount of crunching required. But I realized that there are there are situations where results of 2 subqueries will be the same, and there is no need for me to run the subquery twice.. (or have it in my code twice). So I would like to wrap one of the subqueries in an if statement and if the criteria are met, use the value from another column that already calculated that data, else, run the subquery as normal .

I have tried just putting the other subquery's alias, but it says unknown column totalSales because the field is in the query, not one of the tables.

Is there any way around this?

**UPDATE:** I have reposted this as a query refortoring question - thanks for the suggestions.. [How to refactor select subqueries into joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878631/how-to-refactor-select-subqueries-into-joins)

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results with your conditional criteria?  Not sure I really understand what you're asking... Sounds like a CASE statement might be able to do what you're looking for though (run a subquery if some criteria isn't met).

Comment: Not really.. I mean I can.. but it's huge data and the sub query is like 25 lines and really isn't relevant to the question... I can do the criteria with a case, or if.. But how do I get the data from another query field?

Comment: There might be a way to better code your SQL query as joins, or to better code the subquery. Can you post a cut-down version of your subqueries that has just the quintessential parts. See [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org)

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a way around this.  The SQL engine compiles the query to run the *whole* query, not just part of it.  During compile time, the query engine does not know that the results will be the same.

More likely, you can move the subqueries to the `from` clause and find optimizations there.

If that is of interest, you should write *another* question with the actual queries you are using.  That is a different question from this one ("how to rephrase this query" rather than "how can I conditionally make this run").

Comment: I have 15 counts if records returned by a subquerys.. Putting them in the from was considerably slower. I'd love to simplify it, but in my testing, this seems to be the fastest way.

Comment: on further research.. I see what you are getting at.. if I put the subqueries into the where as a join, I could use them more than once. Reposted as suggested - see edits above.